# How to Auto Increment a column in postgres? Like some fixed text after that incrementing number

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to postgres and trying to create a schema.
I Have a requirement in which i need to auto increment the Id column of my table. But i dont want it to be just a number but some fixed value followed by incrementing number.
Example -

```
DAG100H001
DAG100H002
DAG100H003
DAG100H004
```

something like this. I was looking at the documentation and found serial but i am not sure how to implement using that.
Any help will appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This looks like a compound key, the reason why you're having issues finding a good solution for how to deal with it is because it's not really recommended to do it like this. Instead split the key into its constituent parts and store them separately, this way it would be a simple numeric field that would have to be incremented.

Comment: Lasse is right. Store an incrementing value in an `integer` column, store the prefix in a `varchar` column and concatenate and format the number when you _display_ it in your application.

Comment: What is instead of 'DAG100H' if we want another field from the same table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a sequence and a prefix:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq INCREMENT BY 1;
```

How to use it:

```
SELECT 
  'DAG100H'||lpad(nextval('seq')::text,3,'0'),
  'DAG100H'||lpad(nextval('seq')::text,3,'0');

  ?column?  |  ?column?  
------------+------------
 DAG100H001 | DAG100H002
(1 row)
```

You might wanna add it directly to your table:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  id text DEFAULT 'DAG100H'||lpad(nextval('seq')::text,3,'0'), 
txt text);
```

So that you can insert values ..

```
INSERT INTO t (txt) VALUES ('foo'),('bar');
```

.. and they get the id you want

```
SELECT * FROM t;

     id     | txt 
------------+-----
 DAG100H001 | foo
 DAG100H002 | bar
(2 rows)
```

- Mind the comments section of your question, as they make a very good point! Consider using a normal numeric sequence and just add the prefix to the client by concatenating it with the column:   `'DAG100H'||lpad(nextval('seq')::text,3,'0'),` ..

Comment: I suspect the OP wants the tenth one to be `'DAG100H010'` rather than `'DAG100H0010'`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you're right.. thanks for pointing out. I just corrected my answer with `lpad`.